# How to combine CosmosDB, Entity Framework and OData in .Net Core 6.0?

Tags: entity-framework, odata, azure-cosmosdb

I have an application that uses Entity Framework, OData and SqlServer in a .Net core 3.1 scenario and it works great.  Ultimately I want to use Cosmos DB on Azure in lieu of SQL Server.

While I can get the app to connect to Cosmos the application fails in calls to FromSqlRaw which the 3.1 compatible libraries do not support.

I've tried upgrading the project entirely to .Net core 6.0 and while this compiles without error I get problems loading assemblies using a package called MediatR (for injection) when the application starts.

My question is twofold: Do the .Net 6.0 compatible libraries for Cosmos DB correctly handle FromSqlRaw and/or is there a workaround for the problem if they do not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can send T-SQL or ANSI-SQL to `FromRawSQL` in EF with the Cosmos DB provider the answer is no.

Cosmos DB is a NoSQL database. The FromRawSQL is intended to allow users to send Cosmos DB's own dialect of SQL and was put in as a way to make the Cosmos provider higher compatible where the provider maybe lacked specific capabilities exposed by Cosmos DB itself.